# Upgrading wp8 to wp8.1 silverlight, Listpicker error upon initialize component

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, listpicker

After I upgraded to Wp8.1 silverlight my listpicker fails during runtime, when `InitializeComponent();` is executed.

The WPtoolKit where the listpicker comes from, has been updated, but still in my solution is: `\packages\WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16\lib\wp8\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll`.

The list picker is displayed in the xaml design view and the code is:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
.
.
.
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LP_Map" Width="284" Template="{StaticResource ListPicker_ChooseCountry_CreateGame_test}" BorderBrush="#FF884900">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ChangeMapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LP_Map}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Background="#FFAB7D33" Content="Europe1328WithWater" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource ListPickerItem_CreateGame_ChooseCountry_test}" />
        </toolkit:ListPicker>

        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Player_LP" Width="150" SelectionChanged="SelChangedCommand" BorderBrush="#FF884900" Foreground="Black">
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Background="#FFAB7D33" Content="2 Players" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Andalus" />
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Background="#FFAB7D33" Content="3 Players" FontFamily="Andalus" />
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Background="#FFAB7D33" Content="4 Players" FontFamily="Andalus" />
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </StackPanel>
```

I do not understand why I get an XAML parse error, is there something I need to update explicitly or change after the re-targeting of the solution?

**Note**
EventToCommand using MVVMLight is not the issue, this has been updated to use the parameter package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ComboBox is not available in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.**

I'm working on WP8.1 Silverlight solution currently, using the latest version of WP phonetoolkit. Have no problem using ListPicker. Here is example:

```
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<toolkit:ListPicker
                    x:Name="MyListBox"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource AppBackground}"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource AppTextColor}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                    <Local:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Local:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <Local:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCategoryCMD, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                        </Local:EventTrigger>
                    </Local:Interaction.Triggers>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And in ViewModel:

```
private void OpenCategory(int categoryIndex) { ... }
```